# Redirect all subdomains to www.DOMAIN.net in Apache (or better: nginx)

Tags: apache, nginx

Usually I do it like this to redirect "DOMAIN.net" to "www.DOMAIN.net" and it works fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@DOMAIN.net
        ServerName DOMAIN.net
        RedirectPermanent / http://www.DOMAIN.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now for a new project I also want to redirect ALL subdomains to www.DOMAIN.net and tried it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@DOMAIN.net
        ServerName DOMAIN.net
        ServerAlias *.DOMAIN.net
        RedirectPermanent / http://www.DOMAIN.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

But this gets me into a loop of infinite redirect, probably because *.DOMAIN.net also works for the "www.DOMAIN.net" and gets caught in a loop.

Can I somehow get an exception into the Alias to make sure that the www-subdomain should not be redirected to itself?

Edit: Just got to my mind that I also use nginx and maybe it would be even better to get it done there. I currently use

```
server {
        server_name DOMAIN.net;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.DOMAIN.net$1 permanent;
}
```

in the nginx config. How to get all (but www) subdomains redirected in the nginx config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it on nginx, you'll need to change your config to the following:

```
server {
    server_name DOMAIN.net www.domain.net;
    if ($host !~* ^www\.) { 
        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.DOMAIN.net$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

This should work out of the box. Sadly, there is no way to avoid using an if in this case.